# use only the year part of a DateTime in where condition (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a column with a DateTime type i want to query the table based on a condition that this data is in a certain year.
I tried this but didnt work

`WHERE YEAR(InvoiceDate) = 2013;` but didnt work

Comment: Tag your question with the  database you are using and show the error.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't want to use functions on columns.  This impedes the optimizer.  This is better written as:

```
where invoicedate >= date '2013-01-01' and
      invoicedate < date '2014-01-01'
```

Note:  `date` is a SQL standard construct for a date literal.  Some databases do not use this.  Most databases support YYYY-MM-DD as a date literal.

Answer (score 0):

Use year(invoice date ) = year (date('01-01-2013')) so that the data type on both the sides are same and the equality operator would be able to compare .
Some database though allow the query to compare the way you have written  Db2 is one such db